# Characterization of effective descent morphism

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory, descent, galois-descent

A faithfully flat morphism of commutative rings $A \rightarrow B$ is an [effective descent morphism](http://www.math.toronto.edu/%7Ejacobt/Lecture9.pdf). So is a regular monomorphism (right?). What is a characterization of effective descent morphisms?

Secondly, what are some reasons to work with the flat topology rather than the topology of effective descent morphisms? I am new to this, but is it not the case that faithfully flat is very similar to being an effective descent morphism?

Comment: See https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/08WE for the first question: the answer is "universally injective maps". This also shows that being faithfully flat is a much stronger property. As to why flatness is important in AG: this is discussed in many textbooks (e.g., constancy of Euler characteristics) but perhaps someone can write a longer explanation as an answer.